# Is it okay to modify a private member variable in an overridden method?

Tags: c++

I'm getting frustrated with some odd behaviour and wonder whether I'm assuming something is fine when it's not. Is the following valid, i.e., can I modify `m_flag` in the overridden `foo()`? If so, something more sinister is happening, as I'm seeing `m_flag` as one thing and then only report its something else when I come to step through `B::foo()` when I know I haven't actively modified it.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
       // Do something.
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    virtual public void foo() {
        m_flag++;
    }
private:
    volatile uint8_t m_flag;
};
```

Comment: That use should be fine. Out of interest, why is it volatile?

Comment: Yes, of course it is valid.

Comment: `m_flag++;` on a bool type?!

Comment: class B does not inherit from class A, so it cannot override `foo()`

Comment: Do you initialise it? Is this really the code that exhibits the problem? How do you see it as "one thing" - is this all in the debugger?

Comment: Quote from Standard: `The use of an operand of type bool with the ++ operator is deprecated (see 5.3.2 and 5.2.6).`. With C++14, your code runs danger of becoming invalid C++.

Comment: Ok, apart from the fact that I ballsed-up the code above, it looks like I'm fine. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Useless It's volatile because I modify asynchronously.

Comment: Your problem is with the asynchronous part then, not the code shown. Note that volatile is not helpful for multi-threading (if that's what you mean by asynchronous), and certainly isn't sufficient to make a load-increment-store atomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I modify `m_flag` in the overridden `foo()`?

<strike>No. Because in the code you posted, `class B` does not inherit from `class A`. This means, there is no `foo()` to override.</strike>

`class B` does itself declare `m_flag` so you are fine modifing it in `B::foo()`.

Please note that, as others have already stated, the increment operator on bool is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but...

The type of `m_flag` is `bool`.  Incrementing a `bool` was
deprecated from the start, and has somewhat surprising
semantics: it is the equivalent of setting the value to `true`.

(The reason for this strange behavior dates back to the early
days of C, when there wasn't any `bool` type.  One particular
idiom was something like:

```
int argsSeen = 0;
//  ...
if ( arg1Present ) {
    argsSeen ++;
    //  ...
}
//  And so on for each of the possible args...
if ( argsSeen ) {
    //  whatever...
}
```

The idea was that by allowing the incrementation, code using
this idiom could change `argsSeen` to type `bool`, and not
break.